# Read previously sent and received SMS messages via iCloud

Tags: ios, iphone, sms, icloud, imessage

I know it's possible because of the existence of [APIs](https://www.reincubate.com/labs/icloud-api/messages/) and [applications](https://drfone.wondershare.com/iphone-data-recovery.html) that do this.

As far as I can tell, however, the relevant APIs are undocumented.

How can I read previously sent and received SMS messages via iCloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[InflatableDonkey](https://github.com/horrorho/InflatableDonkey) is an open source project that downloads iCloud backups.

SMS messages are stored in `target/backups/<icloud_username>/<hash>/<date_str>/HomeDomain/Library/SMS/sms.db`, which is an SQLite3 database.